# jwplayer width loading smaller why?

Tags: jwplayer

Please take a look at the page; http://www.songarea.com/music-codes/akon.html

what is causing this width (player width loading smaller than 300) problem anyone have idea?

my jwplayer configuration is ;

```
        <div id=\"container\">Loading the player ...</div>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        jwplayer(\"container\").setup({
        flashplayer: \"/images/songarea/soso/player.swf\",
        file: \"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$youtube_id."&feature=youtube_gdata_player\",
        stretching:\"exactfit\",
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'controlbar.idlehide': 'false', 
        'autostart': 'false',
        'volume': '25',
        'height': '200',
        'width': '300',
        skin: \"/images/songarea/soso/skins/smooth.zip\"        
        });</script>";
```

Comment: I looked at the link - http://www.songarea.com/mc/1/akon.html#.UNptaHeypvF and I see the player here, but you are setting the width to 480 here, and the player is displaying at 480...it make sure I took a screen capture and measured it. Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: problem still exist. on the previous page, below there is a video >> http://www.songarea.com/music-codes/akon.html

Comment: It looks like you have the following on this page:

'height': '200',
'width': '300',

However, you also have:

<td style='padding:5px;' width="50%" align="left" valign="top">

I think width="50%" is causing this. Can you remove that?

Comment: i solved the problem it was about div id names in different css files. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working!